# VBA Fastest way to filter for 2 specific conditions

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet called gar_nv of 2553 rows and 135 named columns. My code looks for a row containing 2 values: produit and acte, and pastes the variable Remb in the appropriate "Col" column. I'm wondering if there's a faster way to do this ?

```
For Line = 1 To gar_nv.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
                'produit, acte, Col and Remb are variables defind above
     If gar_nv.Range("GCGAR6").Rows(Line).Value Like produit Then
           If gar_nv.Range("GCBARB").Rows(Line).Value Like acte Then
              gar_nv.Range(Col).Rows(Line).Value = Remb    
           End If
      End If
Next Line
```

Comment: What is Range("GCGAR6") and Range("GCBARB"). It sounds like it's easier with a simple formula in column "col". Something like `=IF(AND(COUNTIF(A1,"*prooduit*")>1, COUNTIF(A1,"*acte*")>1), "Remb", "")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write the ranges to variant arrays, as iterating through those would be much faster, e.g.

```
Dim GCGAR6, GCBARB
GCGAR6 = Range("GCGAR6").Value2
GCBARB = Range("GCBARB").Value2
.....
For Line = 1 To gar_nv.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
                'produit, acte, Col and Remb are variables defind above
    If InStr(1, GCGAR6(Line, 1), produit) Then
        If InStr(1, GCBARB(Line, 1), acte) Then
              gar_nv.Cells(Line,Col).Value2 = Remb    
        End If
    End If
Next Line
```

Comment: I edited your 9th line like so : gar_nv.Range(Col).Rows(Line).Value2 = Remb and it works like a charm. Thanks!